# Arreglar error Http500 en código Php alojado en Hosting InfinityFree

Tags: php, php7, php5

Hola equipo de stack overflow les escribe Hernán Martínez espero se encuentren bien
Quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente, agradezco de antemano su colaboración tengo el  siguiente archivo con nombre index.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("puesto", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
  $sql="Select Distinct Artista From discos ORDER BY Artista ASC";
  $res1=$mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <center> 
     <head>
      <title>Listado Discos </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Artista.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
      table{
          border:1px solid;
          border-collapse:collapse;
          padding: 10px;
          }
         th, td, tr{
            border: 1px solid; 
         }
      
      </style> 

     </head>   
        <body>
         Seleccione Artista:
         <select id="Artista" onchange="seleccioneArtista()"> 
          <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
            ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $rows['Artista']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['Artista']; ?>  </option>  
           <?php
            }
            ?>
         </select>
         <table>
             <thead> 
               <th style="width: 30%">Iddisco</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Artista</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Trabajo</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Género</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Año</th>
               <th style="width: 30%">Enlace</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="ans"> 

             </tbody>
         </table>
        </body> 
   </center>     
</html>
```

Tengo otro archivo con nombre showArtista.php, Cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
  $k=$_POST['id'];
  $k=trim($k);
   $con=mysqli_connect"puesto", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
  $sql="Select * From discos where Artista='{$k}'";
  $res1=$mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
?>      
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Iddisco']; ?>Iddisco</td>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Artista']; ?>Artista</td>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Trabajo']; ?>Trabajo</td>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Género']; ?>Género</td>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Año']; ?>Año</td>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Enlace']; ?>Enlace</td>
 </tr>

<?php
}
echo $sql;
?>
```

Además, tengo una carpeta con nombre js, la cual tiene los siguientes archivos en Javascript:

Artista.js:

```
function seleccioneArtista(){
  var x = document.getElementById("Artista").value;
   
$.ajax({
   url:"showArtista.php", 
   method: "POST",
   data:{
       id : x
   },
   success:function(data){
       $("#ans").html(data);
   }

})
}
```

Al momento de correr el programa, no me muestra la pagina web, como bien se sabe no se ejecuta el archivo index.php, me muestra el siguiente error:

Esta página no funciona
La página mipagina.epizy.com no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500

La manera mas adecuada es ubicar la carpeta con nombre config y luego ubicar el archivo con el  nombre define_inc.php y ahí debemos de realizar los reajustes  correspondientes en el código, el inconveniente que veo es que no encuentro los archivos correspondientes en el hosting gratuito que estoy utilizando (InfinityFree).

Muchas gracias anticipadas, por la colaboración que me puedan brindar en la solución de ese inconveniente.

Comment: Será que [la documentación de InifnityFree](https://forum.infinityfree.net/docs?ascending=false&category=21&topic=49354) ayuda?

Comment: Prueba cambiando esto: `$res1=$mysqli_query($con,$sql);` por esto `$res1=mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Comment: @masterguru ¿qué diferencia hay entre uno y otro? Sugieres que cambie algo por su idéntico si no se me escapa algo ¿?

Comment: Para saber con certeza lo que está ocurriendo agrega estas tres líneas justo al principo de tu scipt php: **`ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`** luego guarda el archivo y prueba de nuevo. Verás el o los mensajes de error. Puedes agregarlos a la pregunta quitando información sensible. Los mensajes de error te dirán lo que está ocurriendo, en qué archivos y en qué lineas de esos archivos. Sin una depuración eficaz te puedes pasar horas y hasta días rompiéndote el coco para encontrar errores.

Comment: De entrada, falta un paréntesis al invocar la conexión, la forma correcta sería esta: **`$con=mysqli_connect("puesto", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");`** De todos modos, la forma procedural de mysqli tiene varias funciones obsoletas, propicia errores como los que ocurren aquí, es verbosa y es anticuada. Deberías considerar el uso de la forma orientada  objetos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, se te escapa el `$` en `$mysqli_query(...)`, también me costó trabajo encontrarlo y creo que, efectivamente, el error puede ir por ahí.

Comment: Ohhh ya ya, buena vista @Triby :) Yo no me di cuenta. El código tiene más errores, como paréntesis sin abrir en `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: @A.Cedano, eso no lo vi. Siempre reviso primero los comentarios para saber si hay algún avance y ahí decido si veo la pregunta en detalle o dejo que los que han colaborado continúen con su buena labor. ¡Bien visto!

Comment: Pues yo a la que encuentro un error tipografico grave me paro y lo digo, y cuando veo que se han enterado y no es eso entonces me meto mas a fondo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en tu código: confusión de funciones con variables anteponiendo `$`, olvido de apertura de paréntesis ... convendría que uses el estilo orientado a objetos, que es más moderno y menos confuso.

Por otra parte, tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, deberías usar consultas preparadas en todo código que implique datos proporcionados por el usuario.

Corrigiendo ambas cosas, el código puede quedar así:

### Primer archivo

```
<?php
  $con=new mysqli("puesto", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
  $sql="Select Distinct Artista From discos ORDER BY Artista ASC";
  $res1=$con->query($sql);
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <center> 
     <head>
      <title>Listado Discos </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Artista.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
      table{
          border:1px solid;
          border-collapse:collapse;
          padding: 10px;
          }
         th, td, tr{
            border: 1px solid; 
         }
      
      </style> 

     </head>   
        <body>
         Seleccione Artista:
         <select id="Artista" onchange="seleccioneArtista()"> 
           
          <?php 
              while ($rows = $res1->fetch_assoc()) {
                printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>",$rows['Artista'],$rows['Artista']);
              }
            ?>
         </select>
         <table>
             <thead> 
               <th style="width: 30%">Iddisco</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Artista</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Trabajo</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Género</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Año</th>
               <th style="width: 30%">Enlace</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="ans"> 
             </tbody>
         </table>
        </body> 
   </center>     
</html>
```

---

#### Segundo archivo

```
<?php
  $k=trim($_POST['id']) ?? null;
  if ($k) {
   $con=new mysqli("puesto", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
   $sql="Select Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Género, Año, Enlace From discos where Artista=?";
   if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
       $stmt->bind_param("s", $k);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($id,$artist,$work,$gender,$year,$link);

       while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
          print("<tr>");
          printf("<td>%s</td>",$id);
          printf("<td>%s</td>",$artist);
          printf("<td>%s</td>",$work);
          printf("<td>%s</td>",$gender);
          printf("<td>%s</td>",$year);
          printf("<td>%s</td>",$link);
          print("</tr>");  
        }
      } else {
        # Falló la preparación, manejar error o lo que quieras
        echo "error en preparación";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Post vacío";    
    }
?>
```

He mejorado varias cosas, buscando un poco de claridad en el código. Por ejemplo, evita las horribles mezclas de bloques PHP / HTML que producen un código que sólo de mirarlo hace daño a los ojos y si intentas comprenderlo te da dolor de cabeza ... en fin... nunca he podido comprender esa mezcla.

Igualmente, he esbozado un mínimo de manejo de posibles errores. Faltan otros, como verificar que efectivamente hay conexión. Por cierto, si vas a conoctar muchas veces, considera crear una clase envoltorio para tu conexión.

Considera también evitar acentos y `ñ` para variables, nombres de tablas y columnas, en un contexto donde no establezcas codificación adecuada, tu código podría fallar con errores fatales. Es mejor usar una convención de nombres en inglés, no sólo por esto, sino porque internacionalizas el código (muy útil por ejemplo para proyectos colaborativos donde intervienen varios usuarios).

Esto debería resolver tu problema largamente, si no entiendes algo, pregunta en comentarios.

Comment: Hola  gracias por la ayuda brindada  le comento que me sirve el archivo index.php que hace énfasis en primera instancia cargar los datos en el combobox.
Pero desafortunadamente el archivo con nombre showArtista.php,cuyo código es el  mismo que usted me paso el día de ayer,pero con la diferencia de que incluí la instrucción  echo para verificar impresión de registros,no me esta trayendo los registros en las tablas correspondientes,vale mencionar que en el archivo de Javascript,que tengo dentro de una carpeta js con nombre Artista.js que es el que tiene la función  seleccioneArtista

Comment: @MartínHernández ¿qué muestra, alguno de los mensajes del código o no muestra nada? Si no muestra nada, conviene que en este bloque de tu Javascript `success:function(data){` pongas un `console.log(data);` y revises la salida que haya en consola.

Comment: Hola Buenos Dias, tan solo me muestra lo siguiente cuando incluyo el console.log(data); dentro del archivo Artistas.js,                                                  me muestra lo siguiente:                                                                                    [Done] exited with code=0 in 0.478 seconds

Comment: @MartínHernández ¿no ves nada más aparte de eso? Parece ser un problema de otro tipo, de permisos, de bloqueo de puertos o algo así.

Comment: Si debe de ser eso, pues me estoy guiando tambien por las ayudas del Php (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) y no veo donde este el error.

Comment: @MartínHernández revisa los encabezados de la respuesta para ver con mayor claridad lo que estaría ocurriendo.